What do the variable bleed valves on a CFM56 engine look like when starting said engine?
What do the variable bleed valves look like internally when starting engines? Does it exist a video of the VBV in operation?

You can see a valve opening and closing in this Youtube video:



This is frm a CFM56-5B engine, seen from the bypass duct, the primary duct is visible through the hole. A bit of explanation:

The control mechanism is actuated by the hydromechanical unit (HMU), it moves a flexible circular shaft commanding the 12 VBV. When the VBV are open, air from the primary flow is dumped into the bypass flow to prevent a compressor stall.
By the way you can also see on the picture the rings of the variable stator vanes, also part of the compressor geometry optimization at different rpm.
Picture and video taken from Why does the CF6/CFM56 Turbofan Fan Frame contain 12 circular holes between the primary and secondary flow?. This question provides additional details and explanations.
